# Decrement column value in laravel but not negative value

Tags: php, laravel

I can reduce the column value using this query

```
 $res = DB::table('leave_summaries')->where('user_id',$request->user_id)->decrement($request->leaveType,$request->day);
```

But i want to restrict the value from being negative value.

Comment: Add a part of the where clause which checks that the value you are updating must be > 0.

Comment: Do you need to set it zero if it's negative or just prevent the decrement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to prevent the negative value, you need to check that your `leaveType` is more than `$request->day`

```
    $res = DB::table('leave_summaries')
        ->where('user_id', $request->user_id)
        ->where($request->leaveType, '>', $request->day)
        ->decrement($request->leaveType, $request->day);
```

Comment: it's worked sir, but how  to display an error message like this 'can't approve this application because leave balance is less than 0'

Comment: You will need to do it in 2 steps, do a count before the decrement. If count > 0 do decrement else return error message

Answer (score 1):

In order not to decrement the column to negative value, you should check if the column is greater than zero in your query, like this:

```
$res = DB::table('leave_summaries')
->where('user_id',$request->user_id)
->where($request->leaveType, '>', 0)
->decrement($request->leaveType,$request->day);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @djunehor,  it would be proper to give some explanation for your answer to be considered an answer